# Pygame's Rect shows strange behaviour

Tags: pygame

Note on versions: Python 3.4 with Pygame 1.9.2 for Python 3.3 (but it works well so far)

I have tiles in my sidescroller which are made up by 64x64 pixel rects, looking somewhat like this:

```
class Tile(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, x + 64, y + 64)
```

(There's of course more going on in this class, but that's not linked to the question now)

In the program I update the tiles' positions by changing their x and y values:

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    for tile in self.tilelist:
        tile.rect.x += dx
        tile.rect.y += dy
```

Long story short: Only the x and y values change, the width and height remain, so the dimensions of the rectangle are changed and not its position. I have this workaround so far:

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    for tile in self.tilelist:
        tile.rect.x += dx
        tile.rect.y += dy
        tile.rect.w = tile.rect.x + 64
        tile.rect.h = tile.rect.y + 64
```

But that's not as I understood this paragraph of the rectangle documentation:
"Assigning to size, width or height changes the dimensions of the rectangle; all other assignments move the rectangle without resizing it"
From here:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

What am I doing wrong? How do I make changes to a rect to move it, if not by what I did there?

I'd appreciate any hint to what I'm mistaking here :/ Thanks!

Pat

//Edit

This is the code of my collision detection. Based upon the theory how pygame rects should work, this should as well. It somehow does, but only when I adjust w and h value of the rect every single frame as well.

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    dx *= self.dt * self.speed
    dy *= self.dt * self.speed

    for tile in self.coll_list:
        if dx > 0:          # Moving LEFT
            if self.player.dir != "l":
                self.player.dir = "l"
            if tile.rect.y < self.player.rect.h and \
               tile.rect.h > self.player.rect.y:
                if tile.rect.w + dx > self.player.rect.x and \
                   tile.rect.x < self.player.rect.w:
                    if tile.category == "solid":
                        dx = self.player.rect.x - tile.rect.w
                    elif tile.category == "item":
                        if tile.func != None:
                            _func = eval(tile.func[0])
                            _args = eval(tile.func[1])
                            _func(_args, tile)
        elif dx < 0:        # Moving RIGHT
            if self.player.dir != "r":
                self.player.dir = "r"
            if tile.rect.y < self.player.rect.h and \
               tile.rect.h > self.player.rect.y:
                if tile.rect.x + dx < self.player.rect.w and \
                   tile.rect.w > self.player.rect.x:
                    if tile.category == "solid":
                        dx = self.player.rect.w - tile.rect.x
                    elif tile.category == "item":
                        if tile.func != None:
                            _func = eval(tile.func[0])
                            _args = eval(tile.func[1])
                            _func(_args, tile)
        if dy > 0:          # Moving UP
            if tile.rect.x < self.player.rect.w and \
               tile.rect.w > self.player.rect.x:
                if tile.rect.h + dy > self.player.rect.y and \
                   tile.rect.y < self.player.rect.h:
                    if tile.category == "solid":
                        dy = self.player.rect.y - tile.rect.h
                        if self.player.jumping != 1:
                            self.player.jumping = 1
                    elif tile.category == "item":
                        if tile.func != None:
                            _func = eval(tile.func[0])
                            _args = eval(tile.func[1])
                            _func(_args, tile)
        elif dy < 0:        # Moving DOWN
            if tile.rect.x < self.player.rect.w and \
               tile.rect.w > self.player.rect.x:
                if tile.rect.y + dy < self.player.rect.h and \
                   tile.rect.h > self.player.rect.y:
                    if tile.category == "solid":
                        self.collisions["bottom"] = True
                        dy = self.player.rect.h - tile.rect.y
                    elif tile.category == "item":
                        if tile.func != None:
                            _func = eval(tile.func[0])
                            _args = eval(tile.func[1])
                            _func(_args, tile)

    for category in ["solid", "deco", "actor", "item"]:
        for tile in self.tiles[category]:
            tile.rect.x += dx
            tile.rect.y += dy
            tile.rect.w = tile.rect.x + 64
            tile.rect.h = tile.rect.y + 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w` and `h` are the width and height and should not depend on position. Thus:

```
    tile.rect.x += dx
    tile.rect.y += dy
    tile.rect.w = 64
    tile.rect.h = 64
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried out. If I do so, then there's absolutely no collision detection working anymore. If I use my way, each collision works precisely the way it should. There's something really screwed up, either by me or python 3.4 and pygame :/

Comment: @PatricHartmann For collision detection, you need to compare tile1.rect.left to tile2.rect.right and title1.rect.top to tile2.rect.bottom . The width and height have nothing to do with this.

Comment: ... or use the colliderect() function for collision detection.

Comment: I'm aware of the colliderect() function, thank you though; I'd like to figure it out on my own to get an understanding of how it works :) But I try with your other tip, that sounds very promising! Though it's bed-time now :D almost midnight here... I'll let you know tomorrow, how it worked out; thank you anyway!

Comment: I figured things out now, thank you very much! I wasn't aware of the fact that w/h don't represent the POSITION of the width/height but only the actual width/height itself (and they never change). You pointed this out to me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

assuming `dx` and `dy` are supposed to be relative and not absolute coordinates, why not use the built-in [move](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) function

```
def move(self, dx, dy):
    for tile in self.tilelist:
        tile.rect.move_ip(dx, dy)
```